# what is the difference between 2 build.gradle files those are included in Corda project

Tags: corda

When I open my cordapp-example in intellj. I can see 2 **build.gradle** files.
One under java-source and another in the cordapp-example directory i.e main director. What is the difference between both of them?

Comment: the only answer we can give you in the current state is they are in different directorys maybe consider adding the code of the 2 build gradles and the structure of your project

Comment: So can we go with only one build.gradle file too?

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the way gradle works for managing multiple separate modules within one top level project. In this case, the cordapp-example has a java version and kotlin version - both have their own build settings and dependencies. The top level build.gradle has configuration and dependencies which are applied to both projects.

You can see that **settings.gradle** contains the following:

```
include 'kotlin-source'
include 'java-source'
```

This defines the submodules included in the project.